# Moving files and renaming when a file exists in destination folder

Tags: macos, bash, shell-script

I used to do this with [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php). I'd move everything from `~/Downloads/` to `~/Downloads/Archive/Pictures`, `~/Downloads/Archive/Documents`, `~/Downloads/Archive/Videos` etc. based on the file extension, and when a file with an identical name already existed, Hazel would just append a number to the file it was moving.

I wanted to write a shell script that would achieve this but I quickly realized I have no idea how to rename the files without any user input. The scheme to rename by could be a simple counter after the filename and it should only take place when `mv` would otherwise overwrite the existing file. It should also be able to continue the counter should there already have been numerous instances with an identical filename. So, if I were moving `dirA/file.ext` to `dirB/` that already has `file.ext` and `file2.ext` in it, the script should start counting at 3 and rename `dirA/file.ext` to `dirB/file3.ext`.

Can anyone offer any guidance on how to go about achieving this? Preferably with a shell script but if not, then either in Ruby, Perl, or Python. Just knowing whether this is even possible with a shell script would help me.

Comment: Sorry for stating the obvious, but why is Hazel no longer an option?

Comment: I don't have a license for it, I want to do this on all my boxes and two of them run Debian, and I want to know how to do it myself.

Answer (score 8):

It's not that hard. If the destination file exists, you just need to break the file apart into the basename and the extension, and increment a counter until the new filename does not exist in the target directory.

```
source=dirA/file.ext
dest_dir=dirB

file=$(basename file.ext)
basename=${file%.*}
ext=${file##*.}

if [[ ! -e "$dest_dir/$basename.$ext" ]]; then
    # file does not exist in the destination directory
    mv "$source" "$dest_dir"
else
    num=2
    while [[ -e "$dest_dir/$basename$num.$ext" ]]; do
        (( num++ ))
    done
    mv "$source" "$dest_dir/$basename$num.$ext" 
fi
```

Comment: no, it's not hard. but considering that this is an every-day-task (compare with  windows explorer which can do the above by itself), I find it rather astonishing nothing close to this is build in to mv.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it with a single command if you have the GNU version of `mv` installed on each workstation. The default shipped with Mac OS X does not support the `--backup` switch. You can obtain the GNU Coreutils for Mac OS X through Macports and many other locations.

Then it's just a matter of:

```
mv --backup=numbered dirA/file.ext dirB/
```

The resulting filename will be `file.ext.~1~`, `file.ext.~2~` and so on.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to glenn, I rewrote the functionality so it supports empty extensions and also accepts direct files as the destination (just like normal `mv` does)

```
mv_no_override() {
    local dir file ext base num
    if [ -d "$2" ]; then
        dir=$2
        file=$(basename "$1")
    else
        dir=$(dirname "$2")
        file=$(basename "$2")
    fi
    ext="$(sed -r 's/.+(\..+)|.*/\1/' <<<"$file")"
    base="$(sed -r 's/(.+)\..+|(.*)/\1\2/' <<<"$file")"
    while [ -e "$dir/$base$num$ext" ]; do
        (( num++ ))
    done
    mv "$1" "$dir/$base$num$ext"
}
```